# How can I defeat Eorforwine?

Tags: assassins-creed-valhalla

I am currently power 135 and Eorforwine is recommended 90. However when I try and battle her she easily defeats me.

I am using a heavy shield and axe setup, and trying to dodge her attacks and then hit her. However I am finding that she either blocks me with the shield and then hits me twice which takes away half my health.

If I try and use range and shoot her with arrows she throws poison bombs at me which I cannot dodge out of the way of because the radius is so big, and she throws three in quick succession.

Whilst I am trying to then close the distance she drinks a healing potion.

What techniques can I use to defeat this Order Zealot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now defeated her. My main strategy was pressure and opportunism.

I equipped a Spear as my weapon, to allow me to attack quicker and easier after dodging, so I didn't need to close as much distance.

I did pepper her with a few arrows, trying to hit the soft spot on her foot.

The key skill was the slow time when dodging, as this allows you to watch for her attack animation and then sidestep it and get a few hits in to deal damage. The advantage of this is that you are close to her, so she doesn't throw any poison gas bombs on you.

Being close up to her also means when she tries to drink her healing potion you can attack her to interrupt it.